# sharp icons crystal clear android app

Tags: android, android-layout

hi good afternoon any ideas in how can i improve png quality of my icons? i used the kit from android developer page but i cant get sharp images i mean crystal clear, do i need to load this icons in a diff way than just draging into my layout? thanks

i use this layout:

```
     <!-- Rightend Arrow -->
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

for example you can see the right arrow icon in eclipse sharp but in emulator and device looks blurred:

[image: you can see the right arrow en eclipse looks sharp but in the emulator and device looks blurred]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide resources for all densities. If you just place one icon in `res/drawable`, that resource will be used and scaled for densities above `mdpi`. So for an `hdpi` device, you're going to see an upscaled (150%) version of your drawable, and for `xhdpi`, you'll see a 200% upscaled version of your graphic.

**This is bad.**

You'll need to create larger versions of your graphic using the 3:4:6:8 ratio, where mdpi is the density (4). You can mostly ignore `ldpi`, but just provide a fallback in `res/drawable`. Your icon for hdpi should be 1.5x larger, and your xhdpi icon should be 2x as large. So for instance, an image you want to display at 48x48dp (device-independent pixels) should be created at 48x48px for mdpi (placed in `res/drawable-mdpi`), 72x72px for hdpi (placed in `res/drawable-hdpi`), and 96x96 for xhdpi (placed in `res/drawable-xhdpi). Android will automatically pick the correct version for your density if you've made it available, and won't scale it.

Keep in mind, the graphics still will be only as sharp as you design them originally.

See [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#icon-sets) for more information.

Comment: thanks very much, one question this is for icons in my app, but what about for headers? i have custom windows title and load a header.png do i need to follow same rules? what u recommend me

Comment: You need to follow the same guidelines for any bitmap graphics you provide for your application. What size you decide to make them is up to you, though, just make sure to maintain the ratio. It's also recommended to start at the largest size (larger than you'll need -- future-proof it! :) ), and keep the dimensions a multiple of 4px to make it easier to scale your graphics down without scaling artifacts.

Comment: ok i know i need to create hdpi xhdpi mdpi and default drawable folder, that default one what size should be?

Comment: i have already icons for hdpi: 48x48px  mdpi: 32x32px & xhdpi: 64x64px

Comment: i downloaded files from android webpage i have that sizes but u write another ones 48x48px for mdpi 72x72px for hdpi 96x96 for xhdpi which one i have to follow

Comment: 48px was an example. Sizing is your call.

Comment: ok i tried to put my image for all hdpi xhdpi and so on, but i still getting blur png

Comment: i loaded like this   `   <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" `
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

Comment: in my pc all sizes looks sharp mdpi hdpi xhdpi but not in device i dont know what else to do i have for each density a diff icon with their size

Comment: By chance, do you have `android:anyDensity="false"` in your manifest? If so, remove it.

Comment: i really dont know whats happening

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17769/discussion-between-alexistkd-and-kcoppock)

Comment: done i fixed it following your guideline also i set android:anyDensity="false" to true and now shows sharp icons

Answer (score -1):

I use MobiOne software to author android apps and I ran into the same blurry icon issues when I was following the 36, 48, 72, and 96-pixel icon sizes rule. Guess what? I replaced the 96px one with 300px image and the resulting icon came out crispy and sharp when viewed on Samsung Galaxy S4. I later replaced the 72px one with 200px image.