# Blurry icons on phone

Tags: html, css

I have some images/icons that are perfectly sharp and they look good in my browser. But i noticed that on my phone they get a bit blurry and i'm not sure why.

This is a screenshot from my phone, where you can see that they are not sharp.

[image: Screenshot]

It's not as clear on the phone since they're much smaller there (screenshots makes everything a lot bigger by some reason), but it is still noticeable.

Code wise i have the sizes set both in html and css:

```
<img src="assets/images/icon.png" height="27" width="28" />
```

I also use these meta tags for scaling (if that makes any difference).

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Also.. It's pretty much the same problem as described in this SO post: [sharp icons crystal clear android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805643/sharp-icons-crystal-clear-android-app)
Except that i have this problem with html/css.

Do i have to make different sizes of the icons, or one bigger sized one? Or how does this work?

Link to the icon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvXwb.png

Comment: can you upload assets/images/icon.png to see it's resolution please?

Comment: many factors that could contribute to it. First, is the dpi(resolution of the image) vs the screen that you are viewing from. If the dpi of the image is lesser than what your screen is viewing, it will be blur. Secondly, blurry images can also be caused by setting the size of the image larger in css than the actual size.

Comment: Uploaded the icon to imgur, edited the post.

Comment: There are many strategies, but the crux of your issue is that you need to provide higher resolution images for displays that have higher pixel densities. Refer to the [resolution media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#resolution).

Comment: So basically i need several different sizes of the icons and then change their link/path with media queries depending on the devices resolution?

Comment: Yeah, you'll different sizes, or a vector image. Just as a recommendation (which you might not be able to take, depending on your project), FontAwesome has a star icon that works at scale (since its vector format): http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/star-o/